# Pass variable to Dockerfile CMD, Nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm getting used to with Docker. Here is my current code in DockerFile:

```
FROM node:12-alpine AS builder
ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV ${NODE_ENV}
RUN npm run build
CMD ["sh","-c","./start-docker.sh ${NODE_ENV}"]
```

And I'm using pm2 to manage cluster in Nodejs, here is my **start-docker.sh**:

```
NODE_PATH=. pm2-runtime ./ecosystem.config.js --env $NODE_ENV
```

In my ecosystem.config.js, I define an env:

```
env_dev: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development'
      }
```

Everything is oke, but on my server, the NODE_ENV=''. I think there is something wrong when I pass in my CMD but can not find out what's wrong

Comment: Can we have the errors, that are commig on server

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no error, So I got stuck :(

Comment: Why dont you set the server's OS env variable ?

Comment: Had you gone through this docment? https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/

Comment: And what is inside start-docker.sh ?. According to the documentation, you do not need to pass the ARG like this. You need to pass the ecosystem file in run command

Comment: I want to specific the NODE_ENV for specific environment that why I used tag "--env", and the $NODE_ENV is my current environment

Comment: Your script would see the environment parameter as `"$1"`; it can also directly access environment variables.  Just saying `CMD ./start-docker.sh` would be sufficient; the `CMD` syntax probably isn't the cause of your problem.

Comment: So  how can it set the NODE_ENV

Comment: I found one solution if we try it with docker-compose. what you think, docker-compose can work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay in my mind there is another way to do this, please try this way. this will not be actual code, it will just be an idea.

> ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "app",
    script: "./app.js",
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: "development",
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: "production",
    }
  }]
}
```

And your dockerfile

> dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN npm run build
CMD ["pm2","start","ecosystem.config.js"]
```

As described in PM2 CLI documentation you just need to run command to start the application using the command `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` this is automatically accessing the ENV variable described in `ecosystem.config.js`

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#cli

Please try this, you might have new problems, but hope problems with some error logs, so that we can debug more. But I am sure that this could work and resolve your problem

Comment: In the document, they say that I have to pass an argument as "--env production" that why I need to pass NODE_ENV to my command

Comment: Is it? I thought this was simple. Just run command pm2 start ecosystem file name. Okay we can pass env variables very easily form docker-compose. If you still need a solution I can provide one.